# Figure out from where user landing on a URL

Tags: reactjs

I have an onboarding page like this [www.abc.com/](http://www.abc.com/) welcome. On continuing users land on /set-profile image page.

There is a Submit on this page.

When users click on Submit button, if the user has come from /welcome,  I want users to go to the configuration page,  else I want users to go to /home.

The issue I am facing is, I tried both window.location and use history but I can't figure out how to find the "from" location.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the browser history from JS (that would be a security issue).
What you can do is add a query string to your /set-profile route (such as ?returnTo=/welcome) and use it for the redirection.